# Work Sheet Event throws an exception called type mismatch error

Tags: vba

Whenever I run this, it is showing me Type mismatch Error (in `If Target.Value = "CustomChoice"`)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Value = "CustomChoice" Then
Range("P12").Value = "Enter Dates"
Range("P13").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Range("R13").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
Range("P12:R13").Clear
Range("Q10").Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Type mismatch of which variables?

Comment: At If condition

Answer (score 0):

This happens because this event fires again in the line `Range("P12:R13").Clear`. But when this line activates, `Target.Address=P12:R13`. And the `.value` property can't be used like you are doing if the range is more than 1 cell.

So you need to modify your code to avoind triggering again this event when Worksheet changes during execution. Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False 'deactivate events

If Target.Value = "CustomChoice" Then
    Range("P12").Value = "Enter Dates"
    Range("P13").Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Range("R13").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
    Range("P12:R13").Clear
    Range("Q10").Select
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True 'activate events

End Sub
```

Comment: Might be worth adding something like `IF Target.Address = "$A$1"` otherwise it doesn't matter what cell _CustomChoice_ is entered in.  @srivardhankandike Could you also tick this as the accepted answer if it works - saves people from looking to answer it a second time.

Comment: yea but in a drop down when CustomChoice is selected then that operation should be perform@Darren Bartup-Cook

Comment: But now im getting new error like thats working very well but when im entering the data on the cell its doesnt showing me anything